# kube-dns and kubernetes-dashboard pods status are CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I setup multi-node Kubernetes cluster (3 etcds, 2 masters and 2 nodes) in OpenStack following the https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html

All VM has CoreOS 1185.3.0

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.4.3", GitCommit:"ae4550cc9c89a593bcda6678df201db1b208133b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-08-26T18:13:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.0+coreos.0", GitCommit:"278a1f7034bdba61cba443722647da1a8204a6fc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-09-26T20:48:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

`kubectl get nodes` return the cluster is healthy

```
NAME            STATUS                     AGE
172.29.0.157    Ready,SchedulingDisabled   1d
172.29.0.158    Ready,SchedulingDisabled   1d
172.24.0.120    Ready                      1d
172.24.0.121    Ready                      1d
```

`kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system` return kube-dns and kubernetes-dashboard pods status are CrashLoopBackOff

```
NAME                                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
heapster-v1.2.0-3646253287-xweg5       2/2       Running            0          2h
kube-apiserver-172.29.0.157            1/1       Running            2          1d
kube-apiserver-172.29.0.158            1/1       Running            1          1d
kube-controller-manager-172.29.0.157   1/1       Running            2          1d
kube-controller-manager-172.29.0.158   1/1       Running            1          1d
kube-dns-v19-h7qyh                     2/3       CrashLoopBackOff   13         2h
kube-proxy-172.24.0.120                1/1       Running            2          36m
kube-proxy-172.24.0.121                1/1       Running            2          37m
kube-proxy-172.29.0.157                1/1       Running            2          1d
kube-proxy-172.29.0.158                1/1       Running            1          1d
kube-scheduler-172.29.0.157            1/1       Running            2          1d
kube-scheduler-172.29.0.158            1/1       Running            1          1d
kubernetes-dashboard-v1.4.0-t2lpu      0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   12         2h
```

Can somebody tell me know how to figure out the exact issue here?

UPDATE:

I was able to get logs of kube-dns and kubernetes-dashboard containers. It seems to be certificate issue when trying to call kubernetes api. I have recreated all certificate and replace them.

Setting up master and worker instructions, 
https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-workers.html

Masters are fronted by a load balancer.

Finally restarted kubernetes 2 master VMs and 2 node VMs. But the problem still persists in the kube-dns and kubernetes-dashboard.

kube-dns container logs

```
docker logs c8c82e68cde9
I1111 16:28:25.097452       1 server.go:94] Using https://10.3.0.1:443 for kubernetes master, kubernetes API: <nil>
I1111 16:28:25.103598       1 server.go:99] v1.4.0-alpha.2.1652+c69e3d32a29cfa-dirty
I1111 16:28:25.103789       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I1111 16:28:25.103928       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I1111 16:28:25.104185       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I1111 16:28:25.104301       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --federations=""
I1111 16:28:25.104465       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I1111 16:28:25.104607       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
I1111 16:28:25.104718       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
I1111 16:28:25.104831       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I1111 16:28:25.104945       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I1111 16:28:25.105056       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I1111 16:28:25.105188       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I1111 16:28:25.105302       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I1111 16:28:25.105412       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --v="0"
I1111 16:28:25.105520       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --version="false"
I1111 16:28:25.105632       1 server.go:101] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I1111 16:28:25.105853       1 server.go:138] Starting SkyDNS server. Listening on port:10053
I1111 16:28:25.106185       1 server.go:145] skydns: metrics enabled on : /metrics:
I1111 16:28:25.106367       1 dns.go:167] Waiting for service: default/kubernetes
I1111 16:28:25.108281       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I1111 16:28:25.108469       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
E1111 16:28:25.176270       1 reflector.go:214] pkg/dns/dns.go:155: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get endpoints)
I1111 16:28:25.176774       1 dns.go:173] Ignoring error while waiting for service default/kubernetes: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get services kubernetes). Sleeping 1s before retrying.
```

kubernetes-dashboard container logs

```
docker logs b1d3b0fa617a
Starting HTTP server on port 9090
Creating API server client for https://10.3.0.1:443
Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

kubernetes node logs

```
journalctl -u kubelet -f
Failed to list *api.Node: Get https://{load_balancer_ip}/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D172.24.0.121&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kube-ca")
```

I followed https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/openssl.html when generating certs.

API server certs generated by below openssl config

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = kubernetes
DNS.2 = kubernetes.default
DNS.3 = kubernetes.default.svc
DNS.4 = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
IP.1 = ${K8S_SERVICE_IP}
IP.2 = ${LOAD_BALANCER_IP}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks

Comment: ETCD is using TLS?

Comment: no. I configured ETCD cluster according to  https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/docker_guide.html

Comment: First try `kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide`. Want to see if the pods have proper IPs. Had this problem and it was related with flannel. Then please take a look at the pods logs and post them here. `kubectl logs kube-dns-v19-h7qyh -n kube-system` and `kubeclt logs kubernetes-dashboard-v1.4.0-t2lpu -n kube-system`. Also will be good to take a look at hosts logs.

Comment: I update with log details. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Looks like the secrets are not mounted inside pods. First check if they were created `kubectl get secrets -n kube-system`. Then you can  ssh into one of the workers and run this: `ls /var/lib/kubelet/pods/*/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-*` You should get something like this: http://pasteboard.co/q47MUYFA3.png.

Comment: Also you can try to describe the pods `kubectl describe kube-dns-v19-h7qyh -n kube-system` Most probably you will see error that default-token can not be mounted. Try restarting the nodes, regenerate tokens by deleting them `kubectl get secrets -n kube-system`and `kubectl delete secret default-token-xxxxx -n kube-system`. There can be more causes including some bugs as I see you are running an alpha version.

Comment: Deleting secrets and re-creating pods work for me. Now I everything working as expected. Thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I can see you have found the solution, please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.